# Encoding problems in Android Application (WebView.LoadData())

Tags: java, android, webview, loaddata

I'm having a problem encoding a part of a webpage in my Android-application. What I've got is a application collecting part of a webpage and displaying this to a user. For this question lets say that I've got a webpage with a text and below the text a table and below the table a lot of junk I'm not interested in. So I'm chosing what to view using the position of the first element (for example a unique  tag) and a end position (same there, something unique. Using a inputstreamreader with a start/end position.

Then in my string ("string") I run:

```
String s = Uri.encode(string);
```

The string s is then used accordingly:

```
web.loadData(s, "text/html","ISO-8859-1");
```

But this gives me some unwanted chars in the middle of the text: "Â" appears. I've tried to in the string run .replace("Â", ""); but this doesn't solve the problem.

I've also tried following:

```
web.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8");

web.loadData(s,"text/html;utf-8",null);
```

But the "Â" and one or two "*" still appears?

Been searching the web and found the: `loadDataWithBaseUrl`but this doesn't solve it either so I would very much like som assistence :)

On the top of the page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="sv-se" dir="ltr">
```

On another page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
```

So I've got one english and one swedish page but the error is regarding both url:s.

Best regards!

Comment: Did you solve this?  I see the same problem.

Comment: No still not completely solved, let me know if you come up with something...

Comment: It may be improper usage on the sender's side.  It only happens occasionally, and probably from certain email clients only. Do you see any patterns?  For now, I'm just  doing s.replace ("\u00A0", "&nbsp;").replace ('\n', ' ');

Answer (score 0):

use this:

> webview.loadData(html_content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");

I tested it, and it works.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me.

```
String base64EncodedString = null;
                        try {
                            base64EncodedString = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((preString+mailContent.getBody()+postString).getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(base64EncodedString != null)
                        {
                            wvMailContent.loadData(base64EncodedString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wvMailContent.loadData(preString+mailContent.getBody()+postString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
                        }
```